# Reset DRAC to factory defaults

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac

I put a DRAC that has not been used in a long time into a PowerEdge 1750 running CentOS 5.8.
Because we run our DRACs on a separate network, we don't change the password from the default (root/calvin), but evidently someone changed this one.
I tried the regular command line reset (`racadm racresetcfg`), but I get the following error:

> ERROR: Unable to perform requested operation.
>   If the operation attempted was to configure DRAC, possible reason may be that
>   Local Configuration using RACADM is disabled.

This implies to me that `racadm` is able to communicate, but there is a setting on the DRAC that is preventing it from working.

I was not able to find any references to this error in any Dell documentation.

Has anyone seen this problem and/or know what I can do about it?
(The DRAC is useless is I can't log in to it.)

Comment: Call Dell? 5chr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the the PowerEdge 1750 actually uses a "sort-of" built-in version of the DRAC (so an add-in card is required, but the ethernet port is built in). It is based on the DRAC 3, so it requires the use of `omconfig rac`.

I manually installed OpenManage 5.4 and I was able to use the version of `omconfig` included with it to reset the password.

Source: http://www.glassblower.info/blog/96-dell-remote-access-controller-drac-reset-password-use/

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the DRAC card during boot with ctrl+D (this is the usual combination but it may change depending on the version). Also may want to have a look at [this](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/power/ps1q08-20080144-bose.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Reboot a server. During POST to press Ctrl+E to open Remote Access Configuration Utility. LAN User Configuration item or Reset To Default. After reset, a login by default: **root**, password: **calvin**
I hope this help. 
[en.community.dell.com](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/956/p/19265139/19452824.aspx)

Comment: My server does not show an option for Ctrl-E, just for Ctrl-D. Is there still a Ctrl-E option on the DRAC 3?

Comment: Yes in DRAC is Ctrl+E and Ctrl+D. http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/956/t/19431032.aspx

Comment: Fair answer - but in my case I use the drac to manage the box.  I need to be able to configure the drac's networking from the installed OS.